# I can't change stock status and manage stock option in Wordpress Admin Panel from Mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce, sql-update

I have a problem with changing stock status and manage stock option by mysql query.

My query is:

```
UPDATE thbc3r4postmeta a JOIN thbc3r4postmeta b ON b.post_id = a.post_id 
SET a.meta_value = '7' 
WHERE a.meta_key = '_stock' AND b.meta_value = '006321';

UPDATE thbc3r4postmeta a JOIN thbc3r4postmeta b ON b.post_id = a.post_id 
SET a.meta_value = 'yes' 
WHERE a.meta_key = '_manage_stock' AND b.meta_value = '006321'; 

UPDATE thbc3r4postmeta a JOIN thbc3r4postmeta b ON b.post_id = a.post_id 
SET a.meta_value = 'instock' 
WHERE a.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND b.meta_value = '006321';
```

My query change values in postmeta table but in Wordpress Panel stock is outofstock and manae stock is off.

Comment: 'My query is' - there are 3 queries here??. You could improve this question by adding sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: I want to change stock status and manage stock option in Wordpress Woocommerce Admin Panel. I think sample data is not nessesary.

Comment: What is that `b.meta_value` related to (what is the meta_key)? You should change that based on the `a.post_id` without the need of JOINing `postmeta` table in each query. Those 3 UPDATE queries can be set in once. Now for the stock status, you also need to update `thbc3r4term_relationships` table as stock status is now also handled as `outofstock` term for the custom taxonomy `product_visibility`…

Comment: So let me get this right your are happy the data has changed but it does not appear to have done so in wordpress panel? I have no knowledge of this product but your observation suggests a refresh or restart is in order.

Comment: LoicTheAztec - Can you help me with new query? Post id is 38703

Comment: LoicTheAztec - Do you need something else for the new query?

Comment: I have excell with sku thats why i use sku meta_value in query